# Display two model in a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two model in the Controller

```
public ActionResult Search(int? id)
{
    var yearSummary = from ti in db.TrainingRecordDBSet
                      join si in db.StaffInfoDBSet
                          on ti.StaffId equals si.StaffId
                      group ti by ti.Year into g
                      select new {
                          Year = g.Key,
                          SHour = g.Sum(ti => ti.Hour)
                      };

    var trainingQ = from t in db.TrainingRecordDBSet.Include("StaffInfo")
                    where t.StaffId == id orderby t.StaffId, t.Tid
                    select t;

    var list = trainingQ.ToList();

    ViewBag.yearSummary = yearSummary;

    return View(list);
}
```

I want to show both "traingingQ" from the database and "yearSummary" in the database, which the "traingingQ" is already success, but the "yearSummary", I don't know how to show in the view, Could my dear friends show me how to do?

here is the coding of the view, and that don't works

```
@var yearSummary = (dynamic) ViewBag.yearSummary;
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @*var yearSummary = (StaffInfoEditViewModel) ViewBag.yearSummary;*@
            @{
                Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Shour);
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Shour);
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Thank You very Much!!

Comment: can you tell what does  var yearSummary returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a class (model) to hold the data the view needs..

```
public class SearchVM
{
  public IEnumerable<YearSummary> YearSummary { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<TrainingQ> Training { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Search(int? id)
{
    var model = new SearchVM
    {
      YearSummary = (from ti in db.TrainingRecordDBSet
                      join si in db.StaffInfoDBSet
                           on ti.StaffId equals si.StaffId
                      group ti by ti.Year into g
                      select new {
                          Year = g.Key,
                          SHour = g.Sum(ti => ti.Hour)
                      })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(ys => new YearSummary { Year = ys.YEar, SHour = ys.Shour {)
        .ToList(),

      TrainingQ = (from t in db.TrainingRecordDBSet.Include("StaffInfo")
                    where t.StaffId == id orderby t.StaffId, t.Tid
                    select t)
        .ToList()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: ^^!! May I know how can I use the data in the view